# Habilitar usuario base de datos

Tags: sql, sql-server, tsql

¿ como puedo habilitar un usuario que este offline ?

tengo un usuario asociado a un Login en una base de datos pero este se encuentra deshabilitado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: que has intentado? anéxalo a tu pregunta por favor.

Comment: la solucion fue esta GRANT CONNECT TO verificaRolUser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solucion al problema fue conceder los privilegios de connect a la base de datos

```
GRANT CONNECT TO verificaRolUser
```